# How to share my Wifi internet to other system?

Tags: network-manager, internet-connection

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and i have an internet connection through my wireless card. I want to share this internet connection so that other systems (like an Android phone for example) can use internet through my Ubuntu PC.